# Como executar scripts Python com entrada em .txt no Windows?

Tags: python-2.7

Olá, sou iniciante aqui no Stack Overflow e em Python, e preciso de ajuda para rodar um arquivo da minha aula, cuja entrada está escrita um arquivo .txt.

Sei que no terminal do Linux, para Python 2.7, o comando é mais ou menos esse:

`python arquivo.py < entrada.txt`

Mas e no prompt de comando do Windows, como faço essa passagem de argumentos?

Já pesquisei bastante aqui no site, mas só achei perguntas sobre puramente rodar o script, adicionar o Python ao PATH, enfim. Não encontrei nada relacionado a arquivos como argumentos.

Obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho como testar aqui mas acredito que `type entrada.txt | python arquivo.py` deverá funcionar no Windows. Se você está usando **Python** em Windows pode ser interessante instalar o [Git para Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win), não pelo **Git** em si mas por ganhar um **Bash** e todas as suas funcionalidades (e facilidades).